# Can't connect to MySQL Cluster Storage (data) nodes

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster

I've deployed a MySQL Cluster with a few nodes, and I want to access the storage nodes directly from another machine using NDBAPI.

When I tried to connect from the same host it worked, but when I try to connect from a different machine I get a socket timeout.

Any clues? There is no strange network setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things to check...

1. In your config.ini file, check that you haven't specified the host that is allowed to connect to this ndbapi slot - check the 'hostname' parameter in your config.ini file or run "ndb_mgm -e show". If you leave out the hostname parameter then you can connect the data node from any host
2. Firewall. Temporarily turn off your firewall and see if that fixes it. If you need to lock down the ports used by the data nodes then set the ServerPort parameter in the [ndbd] sections or the [ndbd default] section of the config.ini file. The firewall also needs to allow port 1186 (by default) for the management node.
3. You've filled up all of the API slots - run "ndb_mgm -e show" to check. If needed, add extra [mysqld] or [ndbapi] sections to your config.ini file and restart your nodes.